# Как изменить $PATH во время установки RPM пакета?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell

Мне нужно, чтобы после установки RPM пакета к переменной PATH добавлялся один путь.

Для этого я собираю этот RPM c `postinstall` скриптом, который выполняется после инсталяции.

Часть RPM spec файла, которая содержит этот скрипт выглядит следующим образом:

```
%postPATH=$PATH:/usr/app/mdg/binexport PATH
```

Однако, после успешной установки пакета $PATH не меняется.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить данную проблему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что при запуске скрипта, переменная $PATH меняется в дочернем shell-е, поэтому вы и не видете изменений. Вам необходимо включить в пакет shell скрипт, в котором:

> #!/bin/bash
>
> PATH=$PATH:/usr/app/mdg/bin

затем уже в пост-установочной секции прописать:

> . /path/to/script

Таким образом вы заставите ком. интерпретатор не запустить скрипт, а прочитать его содержимое. Можете проверить запустив в ручную.

Comment: @pyatak, я проверил. Действительно теперь код в скрипте выполняется в том же шелле, однако почему-то после того как RPM устанавиливается полностью в главном шелле по-прежнему нет никаких изменений.Я пробовал затем использовать export PATH в пост-установочной секции, но это не дало результат.Вероятно это связано с тем, что теперь переменная PATH меняется для SHALL в котором выполняется установка RPM пакета, а мне надо что бы изменялась переменная родительского SHALL ( т.е. SHALL в котором я запустил установку )